# How to find "max"

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        for(int i = 0;i<=5;i++){
            int N = scanner.nextInt();
            int max = 0;
            if(N > max) max = N;
        }
        System.out.println("bbb " + max);
    }
}
```

I enter 5 numbers and there must be a maximum among them, but the compiler says that the "max" is not found.

Comment: You need to put `max` before the loop.

Comment: ^^ after which, the next thing to consider is: what if the user enters only negative numbers?

Comment: @Ṁữŀlɪgắnậcễơưṩᛗ I put,but instead of the maximum all numbers are displayed in a row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are defining and setting your max variable inside the loop. Thus every time you run it, it will set the var max to 0 again. Your code needs to look like this:

```
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int max = 0;
        for(int i = 0;i<=5;i++){
            int N = scanner.nextInt();
            if(N > max) max = N;
        }
        System.out.println("bbb " + max);
    }
}
```

Comment: I fixed the formatting of the code. You should still mention that it does not work for negative numbers (hint: `Integer.MIN_VALUE`), and instead of `N` the variable should be named `n` since in Java the variable names are usually written in lowercase.